# Project Euler # 27 using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

[This Project Euler question](http://projecteuler.net/problem=27) has me a little bewildered.

Here is my solution that I thought was correct:

```
import math
start = time.time()
def check_prime(a, b, n):
    num = n**2 + a * n + b
    mod = 3
    if num >= 0:
        check = int(math.sqrt(num))
    else:
        return False
    while mod <= check:
        if num % mod == 0:
            return False
        mod += 2
    return True
def main():
    n = 0
    max_n = 0
    for a in xrange(-1000, 1000):
        for b in xrange(-1000, 1000):
            while check_prime(a, b, n):
                n += 1
                if n > max_n:
                    max_n = n
                    product = a * b
        n = 0
    print max_n, product
    print time.time() - start
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This gives me a consecutive prime list of 376 where the actual list is only 71. I think I am just having difficulty understanding the question. Wouldn't the longest prime list have to be at least 80 since that is the one given as an example? My program computes the product of the two terms for the 71 list, but then it keeps going up to 376.

Is there something in the question I am overlooking?

Comment: Just looking at it quickly, I see off-by-one errors in the `for` loop bounds.

Comment: You reset `n` in the outer loop. I'm pretty sure you want to do that in the inner loop, or refactor your code so you don't need those error-prone counter variables.

Comment: Ugh, yea.  I thought it was <= 1000 but it is just < 1000.  Still the same result.  Thanks though.

Comment: Woooowww, I can't believe I overlooked that.  I moved the `n = 0` to the inner loop and it worked perfectly and shed 3 seconds off the time.  Thanks man.

Comment: The longest list doesn't need to be at least 80 long, because the example has `abs(b) >= 1000`.

Comment: Also note that your check_prime function does return True for a = 0, b = 0 and n = 2**x or basically every time n**2 + a * n + b is a power of 2

Comment: The `n = 0` has to be before the while loop, because thats where you start checking one combination of a and b.

Comment: I recommend you do yourself a favor and code a better prime checking function, and save it in a separate module that you can import when you need it. You'll be using it a lot in solving Project Euler problems.

Comment: @MiklosAubert I was thinking about that, but I am still learning Python so I want to get as much practice with the syntax as possible.

Comment: @Josh, how was this solved exactly? Instead of editing the title to add "[solved]" it would IMHO be better if you submitted an answer of your own (and accepted it).

Answer (score 2):

> Wouldn't the longest prime list have to be at least 80 since that is the one given as an example?

The formula given in the problem statement is `n²  79n + 1601`, so `a = 79` and `b = 1601 > 1000`. Therefore, you shouldn't expect the number of consecutive primes to be greater than 80. In fact, 71 is the correct number of consecutive primes. Now you just need to make sure your `product` is correct.

Hint:

> the value of `a * b` is negative.

Comment: Yea, I wasn't paying close enough attention and was overlooking the fact that 1601 is obviously > 1000.  Thanks though.